# How to visualize data with Qt QwtPlot3D

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, plot, visualization

I have a problem using `Qt`+`QwtPlot3D` library.

I need to visualize the data. The data is a simple matrix 5x5. Values are float numbers.

For example like this:

```
0  0    0    0     0
0  4,5  0,5  1,5  -2
0  0,5  2    0,5   0
0  0,5  0,5  0,45  0
0  0    0    0     0
```

[image: This matrix visualisation]

I try out all examples. I understand to use library I should create class with reloaded `operator` with inheritance from class `Qwt3D::Fucntion`.

```
double operator (double x, double y);
```

This way is not for me becase I have no `z = f(x,y)`, I have only coordinates.

---

In the [official manual](http://qwtplot3d.sourceforge.net/web/navigation/manual_frame.html) I found this function:

```
bool loadFromData(double **data, unsigned int columns, unsigned int rows, 
                  double minx, double maxx, double miny, double maxy)
```

But there is no example or sample how to draw the plot using this function.

Can you help me to find the way to draw my matrix in Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the delays are not critical for you, just use the `QProcess` to execute gnuplot.exe. Save plot to *.png. And then open image in your program

Comment: Delays are critical. And how much time does it take for rendering?

Comment: It depends on the speed of your HDD. It takes a few milliseconds to plot your matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about this library. It's too old, though it was updated recently. Use `MathGL`.

Comment: Yes, I’ve already tried `MathGL`. It did not compiled by `CMake`+`MinGw`. I tried on Windows7 x64.

Comment: I do not remember exactly. First of all It cann’t find `libPng` and `zLib`. Then it needs `OpenMP`. I looked at the size of `OpenMP` library and decided to stop compiling `MathGL`. For 2d pots I use `QCustomPlot`. It's tiny and nice and simple for usage. I try to find something similar for 3d plotting.

Comment: The simplest utility for 3d plotting is gnuplot.

Comment: It is a standalone program. I suppose it is necessary to organize the pipeline.

Comment: You can try `gnuplot++` and `gnuplot-iostream`.

Comment: I cann't find sources of `gnuplot++`. `gnuplot-iostream` uses `boost` library, but I don't have it.

Comment: Hmm... look at this project (https://github.com/kedrzu/SinsGP). It's not mine. There are sources of `gnuplot++`.

Comment: This guy use boost too :(